# Unable to remove margin/padding above and below a p element

Tags: html, css

https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/

The element in feature is only triggered when you hover over the shopping cart, so you will need to do so to reveal it.

With respect to the resulting hover drop-down I can't figure out how to make the  grey bars above and below the "No products in the cart" message black.

[image]

I have already tried reducing all margins and padding to zero, and declaring `blackground: black`.

```
#site-header-cart > li:nth-child(2){
     background: black;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
 .site-header-cart * {
     background: black;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
 .widget_shopping_cart{
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     background: black;
}
 .widget_shopping_cart_content{
     background: black;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
 .widget_shopping_cart > p {
     margin: 0;
     background: black;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
 .woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message{
     background: black;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
```

Edit: HTML below:

```
</ul></div>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
<ul id="site-header-cart" class="site-header-cart menu">
   <li class="">
      <a class="cart-contents" href="https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/cart/" title="View your shopping cart">
      <span class="amount">&#036;0.00</span> <span class="count">0 items</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="widget woocommerce widget_shopping_cart">
         <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Linking to an external website is not sufficient, please provide a working example.

Comment: Can you please provide the html?

Comment: Sorry; now appended to original post.

Comment: If you are not using debugging tools such as Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Developer Tools, I suggest you familiarize yourself with them. E.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Debugging_HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is making margin:

```
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message {
    margin: 1.41575em;
}
```

Location: `https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/wp-content/cache/jch-optimize/b0effbedde43bc37217434081fca7177_2.css`

To make them black remove margin and add padding instead:

```
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.41575em;
}
```

Comment: You have to add `margin: 0;` to your last bit of code to make it fully work.  :)

Comment: @ptrcao Ah yes `margin:0` then `padding`. I've changed my answer I hope it helped you.

Comment: The value still needs to be changed to zero.  :)

Comment: @ptrcao Yeah it's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You have this class in your CSS :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart, .main-navigation ul.menu ul.sub-menu, .main-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.children {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

This explicitly tells your cart to be of color `f0f0f0`.

Remove it, and it becomes black !

Comment: Unfortunately I can't touch that CSS file, but I can override with another CSS file - so I tried overriding with `background-color: black !important;` but it didn't work. :(

Comment: You can't touch that CSS file, but you have the whole CSS selector right here, you just have to create another CSS file and override it !

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is what I meant.  However, when I tried to add `background-color: black !important;` to the overriding CSS file, it didn't remove the black bars.  I'm not sure if I did anything wrong but I couldn't get it to work...  :(

Comment: Did you select the div with this selector ? `@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart, .main-navigation ul.menu ul.sub-menu, .main-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.children`

Comment: Ahah!  I know why; it works now.  I needed to apply it universally, not just `@media screen and (min-width: 768px){}`!  Upvote for working solution; unfortunately, to be fair I had to give the accepted solution to the one which was offered first.  But thank you; upvoted!

Comment: Ahah no problem, I'm here to help first ! As long as your issue is resolved, I'm fine with it. Thanks for the upvote though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
#masthead * {
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: I get a warning from my CSS editor "The universal selecter (*) is known to be slow" so I have been afraid to use it.  It's apparently bad practice and slows down your webpage?

Comment: [Custom CSS Pro](https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=custom-css-pro&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550), a WordPress plugin.

Comment: Either way, I'm upvoting your solution for effort and the fact that it works.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to edit your html by adding the attribute `style="margin:0px;background:black;"`. an other solution is to add `!important` tag to your css !

```
#site-header-cart > li:nth-child(2){
     background: black !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
     margin: 0 !important;
}
 .site-header-cart * {
     background: black !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
     margin: 0 !important;
}
 .widget_shopping_cart{
     padding: 0 !important;
     margin: 0 !important;
     background: black !important;
}
 .widget_shopping_cart_content{
     background: black !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
     margin: 0 !important;
}
 .widget_shopping_cart > p {
     margin: 0 !important;
     background: black !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
}
 .woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message{
     background: black !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
     margin: 0!important;
}
```

I think the problem came from the widget you use !

*(remove the grey color :*

```
site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart,
.main-navigation ul.menu ul.sub-menu,
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.children {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

*)*

Comment: Yup it works; unfortunately @trichetriche beat you to it!  Upvoted for correct solution and effort!